Why not using standard operations to manage the airport issue in Scorpion?
I started to watch the Scorpion series and in S01E01 the team uses some crazy ways to save the day. Note that I am not criticizing the reality of the solution - this is a fun series to watch with your brain on standby.
What bothers me is that standard solutions were not used for an ultimately generic incident (the control tower is unavailable). Out of my head I can imagine

planes landing on their own by using the normal rules of priority
since this is a large airport, then up the game by having army jets coordinate the landings.

They had enough time to realize there is a problem and trigger an emergency procedure such as the fighter jets.
I understand that for the sake of the show having someone dropping a random Ethernet cable and connecting it to a moving car looks way cooler (and it does) but I am afraid that I missed something explaining why the obvious solutions were not used.

Pretty much there weren't any. The plot required that there were no other methods considered. Frankly the plane could have landed without any issues without control tower support but that's not dramatic enough hence... a fly-by. This is one of those times switching off the logic centers of your brain is a requirement.

At a larger airport, I’m pretty sure loss of the control tower or communications with the control tower would lead to all planes with enough fuel to divert to a different airport and others to declare emergencies on the same frequency as ATC and negotiate landing directly with the other nearby planes. I can’t see how adding military aircraft to the situation would help at all. Obviously all outbound flights would stay on the ground. Pilots do learn how to operate at airports that have no controllers.

@ToddWilcox I assumed that all communication is failing so the planes either follow the standard rules of priority (like in smaller airfields with no control tower) or, for added suspense, could be directed by military planes (because large airport, much danger, such risk)

Now I see the incident is at LAX. The largest planes couldn’t safely land at nearby Burbank or John Wayne airports because the runways are too short, but most planes (like 737s) could easily divert to Burbank. Also a software failure would almost certainly not take down radio communications but could majorly disrupt radar services for ATC.

What do you mean by “all communication is failing”? You mean somehow all the radios of nearby planes would stop working? That makes zero sense.

@ToddWilcox the whole series makes zero sense. I can imagine that software bug something something all communication lost - I am not trying to make sense of the incident but confirm that I did not miss anything that would exclude the obvious standard operation procedures.

At uncontrolled airports pilots communicate directly with each other. If you want to imagine a magical hypothesis where somehow all the aircraft in the vicinity of LAX and only those aircraft don’t have radio then that’s far enough removed from reality that trying to think of what would happen in that situation in real life doesn’t make much sense. It’s like asking what would a real magician do if their spell backfired. Planes with both transmitter and receiver failures can communicate with airports using light signals.

See https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-would-an-airplane-land-if-the-on-board-radio-breaks-down#3798

@WoJ: "the whole series makes zero sense" -> reminds me of Roger Ebert critic about that 1989 movie, (also listed in the "The 100 Most Enjoyably Bad Movies Ever Made"). It's bad, and you can see it as just that and despise it, or enjoy it for its badness and kitsch carelessness of almost anything (but the music) :) ... well, that one scorpion has no music like this one

@OldPadawan I love such a series. You know, I have a PhD in physics and work in cybersecurity and IT, so I am not looking for a documentary but rather something fun to watch. I am also a Harry Potter fan :) What just annoyed me is that the obvious solution is not chosen and I was not sure why. It is like someone suffocating in a room but not opening the door on which there is a big EXIT sign.

@WoJ : that's exactly the Bellisario effect mentioned in the accepted answer, it works so well for so many movies and shows... Thumb up for HP! Huge fan too :D May the Force be with you!

I don't think you missed anything. I remember having the same reaction as you, and I remember going through the entire episode in my head, same as you.
It's just an example of Bellisario's Maxim.
In case of a complete power failure or failure of the radio equipment, ATC has battery-powered handheld radios. If radio communication is jammed, light guns can be used. For anything not involving the actual movements on the airport surface, or in very close proximity, other ATC facilities can take over. In case of structural failures of the building, emergency relocation sites exist.
And even if all that fails, and there are really no services available at all, a condition referred to as ATC Zero, flights operating under Visual Flight Rules can still operate just as they would in uncontrolled airspace.
The vast majority of airports in the world are uncontrolled. The vast majority of takeoffs and landings happen at uncontrolled airports. While generally, more accidents happen in General Aviation than in Commercial Air Transport, that is because GA pilots have vastly lower training and certification requirements, and their airplanes are vastly less safe and less well-maintained than Transport Category airplanes. The fact that most of the airports are uncontrolled is a lot less significant.



Here is a video on YouTube containing radio recordings of a scenario where an international airport went to condition "ATC Zero", meaning there were absolutely no air traffic control services available. The standard procedure is simply that, instead of speaking with ATC, all the pilots just announce where they are, what they are doing, and where they are going, on the open channel, so that everybody else can hear it. You can also hear one instance where one pilot advises two other airplanes that they might not be able to see each other.
In this case, as far as I understand, the reason was that a controller had a positive CoViD-19 test and the whole facility was closed and cleaned. Which, prior to 2020, probably would have counted as an unrealistic premise in its own right!
A similar thing happened at Las Vegas and Chicago Midway in 2020.



This is Anchorage evacuating the tower because of an earthquake. Something similar happened just recently in Newark, except here, a temporary ATC facility was set up in a different building with almost no reduction in services.



And a power failure at Miami International.
Without ATC services, some rules change, e.g., the airplanes need to stay further apart, etc. But other than that, many professional pilots also fly small GA planes out of small GA airports in their private time, so this situation would be nothing unusual to them.
